# Which is the best way to organize your Bills , Invoices etc online

Tags: organizer-software

I am very much dis-organized sort of person. usually when ever i have any important piece of paper , letter , document , bill . i forgot or throw it and sometime when i need it years later then i repent it.

I was thinking that i should scann evrything from bills , letters , Business cards.

But my main worry is how i can organize them or where should i store them online.

May with some category Listing dates , search etc.

even if its paid thats ok

It it possbile in Google Docs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible in Google Docs, however I wouldn't recommend scanning all of your personal documents and putting them online as a solution.

No matter how secure Google Docs may be, if someone gets a hold of your password, through a keylogger or any other method, all of your private information is visible to them through these documents. Maybe an installable software solution would be more applicable. You can scan your documents and sort them easily with [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) for example.

Comment: Actually i have made a separate gmail account which no one knows and i am putting all personal stuff there. Actually i want something like i e,g i have separate sheets in spreadsheet for each item. Is it possible to link the uploaded item in spread sheet column or row

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but through Google Docs you can sort all of the files into folders. With picasa, you can also publish everything to sorted web albums. So yes, organizing the data is fairly easy. I still strongly advise against putting things on the internet though.

Comment: Concur!  Just google 'gmail security' http://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+security for an idea of how many times google users have had their security compromised.  I have a gmail account, but use it only for things I am OK with releasing publicly to the world - definitely NOT personal information or finances!!

Comment: Then what should be done for sensitive information

Comment: I have addressed that in the last paragraph of my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Evernote may be a solution. It's a desktop/mobile/web application. You can scan documents in and it will push it to Evernote's server to OCR it. They have a backup of it and you can access it anywhere via their desktop application, mobile application, and web application. They have both a free service and a premium service. The biggest difference is SSL encryption and bigger upload limit.

I personally use DevonThink. It has a big price-tag no doubt, and it only works on Mac. However, I can't live without it. It does OCR and organization. The interface is a little less user-friendly than Evernote, but it has its uses for those who like to maintain links between their data.

Answer (score 0):

How about scan your stuff, but store it locally?  Use a local indexing service such as [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/features.html) for Windows or Mac, [Spotlight](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2531) for Mac, or [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/features.html) for linux.

All are good ways to make your files easy to find no matter how they are organized.  Also eliminates any security problems, but you will have to back up your data yourself.

I have used desktop search tools for years to keep a variety of business, finance, & music organized.  Works great.

Comment: I will keep it local but if its online then easy to find or see something important wherever you are